# Error when using a bash here-doc "unexpected end of file"

Tags: bash, ssh

I get the following error that is flagging on the last line of my code (which is empty):

```
syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I can't figure out why it's saying this.  I'm simply trying to use a `here-doc` for an ssh connection:

```
#!/bin/sh

connectToServer() {
   ssh -t root@$1 <<- ENDSSH
      echo "Connected to server!"
   ENDSSH
}

connectToServer $1
```

What's wrong with this code?

**EDIT**

Thanks to those of you who helped me to troubleshoot this.  There were a couple of things wrong with my script; I was using spaces on the line:

```
echo "Connected to server"
```

instead of tab characters.  I was also including spaces before the closing `ENDSSH` which was causing the EOF.  These changes were a part of my problem, but the final thing that resolved it was removing an additional space character that appeared AFTER my closing `ENDSSH`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Problem is spaces before closing `ENDSSH`. Take out all the leading spaces before `ENDSSH`.

Comment: I just tried this and the error is the same.  :-/

Comment: I reproduced same error by putting spaces before closing `ENDSSSH` It goes away when I stripped all leading spaces.

Comment: I piped my script to `hexdump -C` and found that it wasn't a leading space or any characters before `ENDSSH` it was a `0a` or newline character following `ENDSSH`.  I stripped that away and now it works.  Thanks for helping me to find this!

Comment: Do you mean `0d`? That's a CR, which means you edited the file on Windows and forgot to convert the CRLF to LF when moving to Unix.

Comment: @Barmar good catch, I just looked at the output from hexdump and it wasn't the `0a` it was an additional space `20` after the closing `ENDSSH`

Answer (score 10):

The `ENDSSH` marker has to be at the left margin:

```
connectToServer() {
   ssh -t root@$1 << ENDSSH
      echo "Connected to server!"
ENDSSH
}
```

When using `<<- ENDSSH` you can indent the marker, but it must be indented with <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters, not spaces.

Comment: I just tried this and on my line where I have `echo "Connected to server!" I removed all spaces and used tabs.  I also removed the spaces from the closing `ENDSSH` and I still have the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `<<-` operator, only leading tabs are stripped from the here document and the line containing the marker. You appear to be indenting the closing marker with spaces, so that line appears to be part of the here document, and since the here document never closes, you reach the end of the file while parsing it.

Comment: Isn't this the same as what anubhava and I answered?

Comment: It wasn't when I was started typing. (I think I missed your comment in the last sentence of your answer, though).

Comment: Note that even with a leading tab before the ENDSSH I have the same issue on Mac.  Fix was to not tab in front of it (even though <<- should allow it).

Comment: Are you sure you had *just* a leading tab, or that your editor wasn't turning the tab into an equivalent number of spaces? This isn't something that would vary between versions of `bash`, which would be the only factor using macOS might introduce.